# How do I define the main/primary record of a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a service with an `account` table and a `profile` table. An account can own multiple profiles, but accounts always have a primary profile. This would initially be the first profile created alongside the account upon registration, but the user could add profiles and set one as the primary profile later.

I've tried the following setup:

```sql
create table account (
    id                   uuid          primary key,
    email                text          unique,
    phone                text          unique,
    created_at           timestamptz,
    primary_profile_id   uuid          references profile on delete restrict,
);

create table profile (
    id           uuid          primary key,
    account_id   uuid          references account on delete cascade,
    username     text          unique,
    about        text,
    created_at   timestamptz
);
```

This doesn't work because:

- You can't even run that to create the tables since they both rely on the other existing beforehand. A workaround would be to create the account table without `primary_profile_id` and alter the table to add that column after the creation of the `profile` table, however...
- Even if you can create the tables, you can't add records to them because you would need the other to exist first to reference it. It is technically possible if you leave `primary_profile_id` as NULL and change it after the profile has been created, but the columns aren't supposed to be nullable, so it's not really ideal.

Is there any good solution to this? I've also considered having a `primary` boolean on the profile table, but then there's nothing on the database side preventing that being true for multiple profiles under a single account.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: create both tables withouth the fk columns , do alter tables adding the columns plus the fk constraint and allow theses constraints to be null.

Comment: would require a update after the insert and creating a third table to bind with these two relations would be a better choise imo.

Comment: *There's nothing on the database side preventing that being true for multiple profiles*. Yes there is a [Partial Unique Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html). It would allow you to create an index only where the `primary` is true.

Comment: @mwalter No it would not require a third table. A third table would be needed for a many-to-many. Not for a one-to-many as described.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of enforcing your requirement with a foreign key is good.

Creating the tables is no problem; you can simply run

```
create table account (
    id                   uuid          primary key,
    email                text          unique,
    phone                text          unique,
    created_at           timestamptz,
    primary_profile_id   uuid,
);

create table profile (
    id           uuid          primary key,
    account_id   uuid          references account on delete cascade,
    username     text          unique,
    about        text,
    created_at   timestamptz
);

ALTER TABLE account
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (primary_profile_id) REFERENCES profile
      DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

A deferred foreign key constraint like that is not checked right when a row is inserted, but at the end of the transaction. So you can add `account` first and then the matching `profile`, as long as you Insert both in the same transaction.

I recommend using `NOT NULL` in your column definitions wherever possible.